# Flutter Switch button not updating visually

Tags: flutter

I have created a simple Darkmode/Light mode toggle switch and used shared preferences and provider to maintain the state. My issue is, when I open the side menu (which has the toggle switch) and I set it to dark mode, the bool value gets saved in via shared preferences and then I exit the Side Menu. Now, if I again open the side menu, the toggle switch visually still appears as off, even though the darkmode/light mode works fine. I am able to read the correct value from shared preferences. I guess I am missing something trivial, but not getting it what it is.

Here is my Side Menu code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:iconsax/iconsax.dart';
import 'package:pinvault/screens/app_lockscreen.dart';
import 'package:pinvault/theme/theme1.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import '../shared/models/theme_provider.dart';
import '../shared/preferences/theme_prefers.dart';

class DrawerList extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerList({super.key});

  @override
  State<DrawerList> createState() => _DrawerListState();
}

class _DrawerListState extends State<DrawerList> {
  static const double listTilePadding = 0;
  static const double listPadding = 0;
  static const double listIconSize = 22;

  var isDarkMode = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    checkTheme();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeManager = Provider.of<ThemeManager>(context);
    ThemePreference themePreference = ThemePreference();
    final TextStyle? textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium;
    final Color? iconColor = Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color;
    //checkTheme();
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listPadding, 0, listPadding, 0),
          child: ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: 0,
            onTap: () => onTouch(const SetAppLock()),
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listTilePadding, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Set App Lock", style: textTheme),
            ),
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, listTilePadding, 0),
              child: Icon(
                Iconsax.lock_1,
                size: listIconSize,
                color: iconColor,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
            isThreeLine: false,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listPadding, 0, listPadding, 0),
          child: ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: 0,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listTilePadding, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Dark Mode", style: textTheme),
            ),
            trailing: Switch(
                value: isDarkMode,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  isDarkMode = newValue;
                  if (newValue) {
                    themeManager.setThemeData(midnightDark);
                    themePreference.setThemeInfo('themeVal', newValue);
                  } else {
                    themeManager.setThemeData(morningLight);
                    themePreference.setThemeInfo('themeVal', newValue);
                  }
                },
                thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
                    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                  // Thumb icon when the switch is selected.
                  if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                    return const Icon(Icons.check);
                  }
                  return const Icon(Icons.close);
                })),

            // activeColor: Colors.blueAccent,

            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, listTilePadding, 0),
              child: Icon(
                Iconsax.moon,
                color: iconColor,
                size: listIconSize,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
            isThreeLine: false,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listPadding, 0, listPadding, 0),
          child: ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: 0,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listTilePadding, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Privacy", style: textTheme),
            ),
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, listTilePadding, 0),
              child: Icon(
                Iconsax.security4,
                size: listIconSize,
                color: iconColor,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
            isThreeLine: false,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listPadding, 0, listPadding, 0),
          child: ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: 0,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listTilePadding, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Terms of Use", style: textTheme),
            ),
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, listTilePadding, 0),
              child: Icon(
                Iconsax.archive_book,
                size: listIconSize,
                color: iconColor,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
            isThreeLine: false,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listPadding, 0, listPadding, 0),
          child: ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: 0,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listTilePadding, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text(
                "About this app",
                style: textTheme,
              ),
            ),
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, listTilePadding, 0),
              child: Icon(
                Iconsax.warning_2,
                size: listIconSize,
                color: iconColor,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
            isThreeLine: false,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listPadding, 0, listPadding, 0),
          child: ListTile(
            horizontalTitleGap: 0,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(listTilePadding, 0, 0, 0),
              child: Text("Log Out", style: textTheme),
            ),
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, listTilePadding, 0),
              child: Icon(
                Iconsax.logout,
                size: listIconSize,
                color: iconColor,
              ),
            ),
            dense: true,
            isThreeLine: false,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  onTouch(navigate) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => navigate));
  }

  checkTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences themePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (themePref.containsKey('themeVal')) {
      isDarkMode = themePref.getBool('themeVal')!;
    } else {
      isDarkMode = false;
    }

    isDarkMode = isDarkMode;

    print(isDarkMode);
  }
}
```

This is my sharedpref code.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ThemePreference {
  setThemeInfo(String key, bool value) async {
    final themeVal = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    themeVal.setBool(key, value);
  }

  deleteThemeInfo(String key) async {
    final themeVal = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    themeVal.remove(key);
  }
}
```

This is my provider code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinvault/theme/theme1.dart';

class ThemeManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  late ThemeData _themedata;
  ThemeManager(bool isActive) {
    if (isActive == null) {
      getThemeData;
    } else {
      if (isActive) {
        _themedata = midnightDark;
      } else {
        _themedata = morningLight;
        ;
      }
    }
  }

  ThemeData get getThemeData => _themedata;

  void setThemeData(ThemeData data) {
    _themedata = data;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `async` code in your `initState`, when you create the Widget, the `initState` is executed but it's async, so while that async method is executing your Widget is displayed.

After you `checkTheme` finished, the value is updated but you are not rebuilding the widget.

The easy fix is adding a setState:

```dart
  checkTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences themePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    if (themePref.containsKey('themeVal')) {
      isDarkMode = themePref.getBool('themeVal')!;
    } else {
      isDarkMode = false;
    }
    
  setState(
  () {
    isDarkMode = isDarkMode;
  });
   

    print(isDarkMode);
  }
```

You could also move this `checkTheme()` in your Provider and call it from the initState

```dart
Provider.of<ThemeManager>(context, listen: false).yourMethod();
```

Just don't forget the `notifyListener`.

**UPDATE**

I think you can improve your code just like this:

```dart
 Future<void> checkTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences themePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     setState(
       () {
        isDarkMode = themePref.getBool('themeVal') ?? false;
      });
    print(isDarkMode);
  }
```

Comment: the SetState results in infinite loop. I tried that as well.

Comment: I see you have this code :   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeManager = Provider.of<ThemeManager>(context);
    ThemePreference themePreference = ThemePreference();
    final TextStyle? textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium;
    final Color? iconColor = Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color;
    //checkTheme();     just make sure this line is commented or remove , you shouldn't call this inside the build method

Comment: summary: don't call `checkTheme` inside your build method

Comment: I didn't understand how that will help? Can you elaborate?

Comment: if you call `checkTheme` in your build method, and your method `checkTheme` call setState, you'll get an infinity loop,  setState refresh your widget, therefore `build` method is called.  Did you update your code with my instructions? If so, update your code in your question to see the error